# Capture URL from URL Scheme in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've added an URL scheme to my app and it opens up (or is brought back to front if already open) correctly when clicked on a link "my_scheme://item_to_add".

I found how to capture the link on iOS:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;`

Anyone can point me to a similar method on a Mac, where I would be able to capture the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found out the answer myself again ;)

```
//Register to the AppleEventManager
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self   andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

And the implement the selector method:

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:       (NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString* url = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
}
```